# Must the image of unit ball be bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, proof-verification, lp-spaces

I am going through a series of true or false questions, one of them is:

> If $\phi:U\to V$ is a linear, $U,V$ are normed vector spaces, must  $\text{im}\,\phi\big|_S$ be bounded, where$S=\{x\in U:\;||x||\leqslant1\}?$

It feels to me like the constraints are not strong enough for the answer to be yes, so I tried to find a counterexample:

Let $U=\ell^{\infty}$ and $V=\ell^1$ and $\phi$ be the identity map. Define $x^{(n)}=(1,1,\dots,1, 0,0\dots)$. Then in $U$, $x^{(n)}\in S$ for all $n$ and converges since constant, but in $V$, $||x^{(n)}||_1\to\infty$ so cannot be bounded.

Does this work? Seemed a little simple but it would be nice if it did.

Comment: if $\phi(S)$ is $\subset \{  y \in V : \ \|y\| \le C \}$ then $\|\phi\| \le C$ and $\phi$ is bounded (and continuous), but if there is no such $C$ then ... conversely if $\phi$ is continuous/bounded then.... and if it is unbounded then..

Comment: Your example has a problem: $\phi$ is not defined on all of $U=l^\infty$ as a map into $V=l^1.$

Comment: @zhw. Ah damn, knew something was wrong. Can something similar form a counterexample or are $\ell^p$ spaces a bad starting point?

Comment: You can use your idea, just take $U$ to be a certain subspace of $l^\infty$

Comment: Can I just mindlessly go for $U\subseteq \ell^{\infty}$ where $U=\ell^{\infty}\bigcap\ell^1?$

Comment: @user329864 Since $\phi(S)$ being bounded is equivalent to continuity of $\phi$, you can always find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $U\subset\ell^\infty$ be the subspace of  sequences $x=(x_k)_{k\geq1}\in\ell^\infty$ with compact support, and define $\phi:\>U\to{\mathbb R}$ by
$$\phi(x):=\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k\ .$$